# reading application yaml property in Hashmap via ConfigurationProperties annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

Given the property in application yaml

```
acme:
  cloud:
    platform:
      incoming:
        webhook:
          headers:
            gitlab: X-Gitlab-Token
```

I've added a configuration properties bean

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme.cloud.platform.incoming.webhook")
public class WebhooksConsumerTokenHeadersProperties {

    private final Map<String, String> headers;

    public WebhooksConsumerTokenHeadersProperties(Map<String, String> headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    public String getTokenHeaderName(String app) {
        return headers.get(app);
    }
}
```

the `getTokenHeaderName("gitlab")` method returns null.

Comment: I was missing `@ConstructorBinding`; removed `@Component` and added this, that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `headers` set from a constructor parameter, do one of the following:

1. Initialize it in a no-arg constructor or at declaration (`private Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();`)
2. Create a setter method for it.

You may need a getter method, `getHeaders()`, too; Spring would use that especially if you choose option #1 above. In general, type-safe configuration properties objects need to be valid Java Beans with a default constructor and valid setter/getter methods for each property.

For more details, see the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#:%7E:text=Getters%20and%20setters,is%20not%20supported.).